# How to create UITextField with placeholder to the left and edited text to the right?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

How to create UITextField with placeholder to the left and edited text to the right?

[image: textfield image]

UITextField itself does not allow using its properties to put placeholder and edited text to different sides. Try to set it in the storyboard -> attributes inspector -> alignment. They are both to the left or both the right. There is no special alignment only for placeholder or only for the text.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To do this you should add a `UILabel` to the `UITextField` which is not editable and doesn't allow touches. Then set the text alignment on the `UITextField` to `NSTextAlignmentRight`.

Answer (score 5):

First, set the text alignment to the right:

```
    [textField setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentRight];
```

Fir the placeholder, you can add it as a subview, or use the `leftView` property:

```
    [textField setLeftView:<your label here>];
```

Answer (score 1):

I just created a custom UITextField subclass that does this. To use it simply create your UITextField on the Storyboard or Xib... put a placeholder text in there, set the text fields class as OBSTextFieldWithLabel and then you can use the following code:

```
@interface OBSTextFieldWithLabel : UITextField
@end

@implementation OBSTextFieldWithLabel
  - (void)awakeFromNib
  {
    [super awakeFromNib];

    NSString *labelText = [self placeholder];
    self.placeholder = nil;
    CGRect labelFrame = CGRectMake(20, 10, 150, 15);
    UILabel *placeholderLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];
    [placeholderLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
    [placeholderLabel setTextColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    [placeholderLabel setText:labelText];
    [self addSubview:placeholderLabel];
    [self setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentRight];
  }
@end
```

This is probably not 100% perfect as the label size is not dynamically set and all...but it should get you up and running and it works :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've written a control that might help you. Essentially it's intended for highlighting a UITextField while it is being edited, but it also has a mechanism for a placeholder on the left, as you can see in the screenshots.

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/sahighlightedtextfield

Hope this points you in the right direction.